# Need to know how to define two fields refering to same parent table in model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys

In banner table  I have another field image_id which also refers to media gallery , I need to know how would I define this  Banner Model , as I already have defined video_id belongsTo mediagallery. I need help on this

```
//********** Banner model ***************************

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table='banners';

    public function mediagallery()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mediagallery', 'video_id','id'); // 2nd foreign key field name , 3td is parent table primary key field name
    }
}

 //*********** Mediagallery model *********************

 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mediagallery extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table='mediagalleries';

     public function banner()
    {

       return $this->hasOne('App\Banner', 'video_id', 'id'); // 2nd foreign key o the child table , 3td is parent or local table 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 relationships. One relationship for videos and another for images.

```
public function videoGallery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Mediagallery', 'video_id','id');
}

public function imageGallery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Mediagallery', 'image_id','id');
}
```

I don't know the specifics of the app, hopefully this helps.